# Understanding the notion of differentiability in euclidean plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f: R^2 \to R $ is differentiable. In my notes, it says that then one have

$$ f(x+h_1, y+h_2) - f(x,y) = \dfrac{ \partial f }{\partial x} \cdot h_1 + \dfrac{ \partial f }{\partial y } \cdot h_2  + |h| o(h) $$

where $o(h) \to 0$ as $|h| \to 0$. Is this a definition or a theorem? I am trying to make sense of it. Can someone give me some intuition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition: $f$ is differentiable in $(x,y) \iff$ there is $a=(a_1,a_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ such that

$$\frac{f(x+h_1,y+h_2)-f(x,y)-a_1h_1-a_2h_2}{|h|} \to 0$$

as $h \to 0.$

End definition.

In this case one can show that $a_1= \dfrac{ \partial f }{\partial x }(x,y)$ and  $a_2= \dfrac{ \partial f }{\partial y }(x,y), $ hence

$$f(x+h_1, y+h_2) - f(x,y) = \dfrac{ \partial f }{\partial x}(x,y) \cdot h_1 + \dfrac{ \partial f }{\partial y }(x,y) \cdot h_2  + |h| o(h).$$